# How to include image path in script

Tags: image, magento2.3.4, script, paths

My script :

```
<script>
require(['jquery'], function($){
jQuery.ajax({
url: '<?php echo $this->getUrl('customwishlist/index/wishlist') ?>',
method: 'get',
dataType: 'json',
success: function(data) {
var wislistAddesCheckData = data;
var itemLenth = wislistAddesCheckData.items.length;
for(i=0;i<itemLenth; i++){
var wislistAddedProductId = wislistAddesCheckData.items[i].product_id;
$(".product-id-"+wislistAddedProductId).attr('src','/pub/media/yt.png');
}
}
});
});
</script>
```

My path :
app\design\frontend\Zero\my_theme\Magento_Wishlist\templates\catalog\product\list\addto\wishlist.phtml

How to include the image path in **$(".product-id-"+wislistAddedProductId).attr('src','/pub/media/yt.png');**

Answer (score 1):

You can use this below code :

### Method 1 :

```
<script>
    require(['jquery'], function($) {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo $this->getUrl('customwishlist/index/wishlist') ?>',
            method: 'get',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                var wislistAddesCheckData = data;
                var itemLenth = wislistAddesCheckData.items.length;
                for (i = 0; i < itemLenth; i++) {
                    var wislistAddedProductId = wislistAddesCheckData.items[i].product_id;
                    $(".product-id-" + wislistAddedProductId).attr('src', '<?php echo $this->getUrl('pub/media/').yt.png ?>');
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

### Method 2 :

```
<?php
$_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$storeManager = $_objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface'); 
$currentStore = $storeManager->getStore();
$mediaUrl = $currentStore->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
$img = $mediaUrl."/yt.png";
?>
<script>
    require(['jquery'], function($) {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo $this->getUrl('customwishlist/index/wishlist') ?>',
            method: 'get',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                var wislistAddesCheckData = data;
                var itemLenth = wislistAddesCheckData.items.length;
                for (i = 0; i < itemLenth; i++) {
                    var wislistAddedProductId = wislistAddesCheckData.items[i].product_id;
                    $(".product-id-" + wislistAddedProductId).attr('src', '<?php echo $img; ?>');
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```